# Can I change the order status terminology in MyBigCommerce?

Tags: html, css, bigcommerce

I'd like to change my order status from "completed" to "accepted".

I contacted the support team at MyBigCommerce but they were able to help. I'm thinking the html/css may be the solution but I need some guidance.

I'm selling a service and after a customer makes a purchase they receive a notification email stating their order was complete before I render the service and it's confusing to them so if I change it to accepted it may eliminate alot of confusion.  If there's a way to customize the order status terminology I'm all ears.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to probably change the server email that is being sent to say something else, but other than that I don't see a way to answer this question.

Comment: No way to change the variable value of completed to accepted in the html/css anywhere? Kinda fishing for that solution because I'm thinking the email pulls the status from the variable %%GLOBAL_OrderNumberStatusChangedTo%% or something along those lines.

Comment: I'm not sure how your server/website is setup, but I know the way mine works is someone places an order online, the website generates a sales order which is pushed to the companies database, and when a sales order is created, the server generates a confirmation email using the sales order number and grabbing the order information from the database, rather than the website. So the email has nothing to do with the website and more to do with the server that is sending it.

Comment: gotcha, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

We have spoken with a represenative from BigCommerce about the possibility of custom order statuses. They have clearly expressed that this feature is not on their development roadmap.

The closest you could get to your desired solution is including an explanation in the email template that is sent on order status changes.

This email template is the "order_status_email.html" file, accessible from the "Edit HTML/CSS" section of your control panel.

[Here's the documentation on email templates](https://support.bigcommerce.com/articles/Public/Email-Template-Files-and-Snippets).